# ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext() is empty but @AuthenticationPrincipal works

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I've been using ReactiveAuthenticationManager in Spring Security + Webflux. It is customised to return an instance of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` which from what I can tell is an what I should be receiving when I call `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(ctx -> ctx.getAuthentication()).block()`. As as far as I can tell I am unable to access the authentication context through both:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

or

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(ctx -> ctx.getAuthentication()).block()
```

And attempting to access those from controllers or components resolves to `null`. I had some doubts about whether I am really returning an `Authentication` instance in my custom manager and it seems like I am:

```
@Override
public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(final Authentication authentication) {
    if (authentication instanceof PreAuthentication) {
        return Mono.just(authentication)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(this::throwCredentialError))
            .cast(PreAuthentication.class)
            .flatMap(this::authenticatePayload)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .onErrorResume(e -> throwCredentialError())
            .map(userDetails -> new AuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getAuthorities()));
    }

    return Mono.empty();
}
```

Where `PreAuthentication` is an instance of a `AbstractAuthenticationToken` and `AuthenticationToken` extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

Interestingly although `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(ctx -> ctx.getAuthentication()).block()` does not work in a controller I can inject the authentication principal with the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation as a method parameter successfully in a controller.

This seems like a configuration issue but I cannot tell where. Anyone have any idea why I cannot return authentication?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since you are using WebFlux, you are handling requests using event-loop.
You are not using thread-per-request model anymore, as with Tomcat.

> Authentication is stored per context.

**With Tomcat**, when request arrives, Spring stores **authentication** in `SecurityContextHolder`.
`SecurityContextHolder` uses `ThreadLocal` variable to store **authentication**. Specific **authentication** object is visible to you, only if you are trying to fetch it from `ThreadLocal` object, in the same thread, in which it was set.
Thats why you could get **authentication** in controller via static call.
ThreadLocal object knows what to return to you, because it knows your context - your thread.

**With WebFlux**, you could handle all requests using just 1 thread.
Static call like this won't return expected results anymore:

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

Because there is no way to use ThreadLocal objects anymore.
The only way to get Authentication for you, is to ask for it in controller's method signature, or...

> Return a reactive-chain from method, that is making a `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()` call.

Since you are returning a chain of reactive operators, Spring make a subscription to your chain, in order to execute it.
When Spring does it, [it provides a security context to whole chain](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/fb7394c1de60a4a8e564327894d99a6f335905ad/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/context/ReactorContextWebFilter.java#L45). Thus every call `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()` inside this chain, will return expected data.

Your can read more about Mono/Flux context [here](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context), because it is a Reactor-specific feature.

Comment: Can you show an example on how to set the security context in the reactive way?

Comment: I still didn't get why I can't subcribe/block inside the controller method but Spring can do it after method termination

Answer (score 5):

I also had a similar problem. so, I uploaded my github for ReactiveSecurityContext with JWT Token example.

> https://github.com/heesuk-ahn/spring-webflux-jwt-auth-example

I hope it helps for you.

We need to create a custom `authentication filter`.
If authentication succeeds in that filter, then it stores the `principal` information in the `ReactiveSecurityHolder`. We can access the `ReactiveSecurityHolder` from the controller.

Comment: It would better if you share important code snippets on SO

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Alex Derkach said, in more simple terms:

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(ctx -> ctx.getAuthentication()).block()
```

will yield null, because you are disrupting the reactor chain.

What you can do is **return the Mono object directly inside the RestController**
Then you will see the authentication context is indeed present.

Answer (score 0):

Today resolved such problem in the next way:

```
Authentication authentication = new UserPasswordAuthenticationToken(userCredentials, null, userCredentials.getAuthorities());

ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
.map(context -> context.getAuthentication().getPrincipal())
.cast(UserCredentials.class)
.contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication))
.subscribe();
```

`UserCredential.class` - is custom class, which contains userId, initials, login and authorities.

Comment: It works. But the issue here that you don't always have authentication in an ordinary place

Answer (score -2):

If you want to access the authentication object inside a webfilter, you can do it like this.

```
@Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, @NotNull WebFilterChain chain) {
    return exchange.getSession().flatMap((session) -> {
      SecurityContext context = session.getAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_ATTR_NAME);
      logger.debug((context != null)
              ? LogMessage.format("Found SecurityContext '%s' in WebSession: '%s'", context, session)
              : LogMessage.format("No SecurityContext found in WebSession: '%s'", session));
      if(context == null){
        return filterHelper(exchange, chain);
      }else{
        // access the principal object here 
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).